# stubbing responses with Cypress

Tags: cypress, stub

I am trying to stub a response of `GET` request which basically returns an array that is filled in the dropdown menu

[image: list]

I tried this code

```
    // stubbing get a list of schedulers
    cy.server()
    cy.route({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/companies/cccccccc-1111-1111-1111-111111111111/attendance/shift-scheduler/schedulers',       // company one
        JSON: true,
        Response: [
            {
                id: "eeee3333-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
                first_name: "Admin One",
            }
        ]
    })
```

But the list still not filled even though I am not receiving any error, however, I cannot see the stubbed `GET` reqguest in the UI of cypress. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Does the testrunner return any information? It sounds like a problem where the response is not what the application expects and therefor not filling the dropdown menu

Comment: @Mr.J. Mmmm nope tried this endpoint with PostMan returns all values correctly ... seems that there is another way to fill the dropdown list in Cypress.

Comment: In the docs for `cy.route`, there is no option for `JSON`, which you have specified there.  Also I'm not sure if it will matter but you have capitalized the R in Response, which isn't correct.  https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Arguments

Comment: Can you show an example of the request/response you're trying to stub?